# FFMPEG on Fedora but PHP Compilation confliction

Tags: php, linux, apache, ffmpeg, fedora

I have running Xampp with PHP5.5 on Fedora from Apache Friend, with default settings what the installer package do on Linux.

When I install FFMPEG successfully and try to load from php.ini it always says:

*

```
11-Oct-2013 14:05:51 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
```

*

The only thing which is confusing me is that when I did phpize even that I already installed xampp server which means I have PHP running. FFMPEG phpize did not work and I had to install php-devel. Does that mean that FFMPEG is configured with PHP, other than the installed with XAMPP? I am not sure what is happening. Whatever I do I always receive this error message in php_error_log file.

It is amazing :) that I just run below command to see what version of PHP is, I have and below are the results which are shocking one because I am in a feeling that I have PHP 5.5 installed and running from XAMMP.

```
[root@localhost ~]# php -v
PHP 5.2.6 (cli) (built: May  8 2008 08:53:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
```

How can I get this covered that if I simple install XAMPP server on linux and want to install and configure FFMPEG along with?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the versions of php and the module you installed do not match. So run make sure both packages are installed from the same source and are both current.

EDIT: According to the [XAMPP site](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html), Fedora is not supported, they specify Ubuntu, SuSE, RedHat, Mandrake and Debian. So I would make sure you do not use the php package provided by Fedora. Or (if you have the liberty), choose a different OS.

Comment: I truly did "yum update" already :( Just to let you know that even after some research I felt that I might have ZEND older version so I set repo file for ZEND package to update and upgraded successfully BUT in vain.... :( I am in a great feeling that when I compile/make/install FFMPEG, it compiled through older version of PHP other than installed and used of XAMPP package.

Comment: If you have php installed through `yum`, I would remove it first so there is only the php version provided by XAMPP left. Then `configure` either finds the correct version of php, or no version at all (in the later case you would have to specify the path to the libraries/headers).

Comment: Yes, I am in a feeling that we are debating very closely. That is my feeling also that I need to remove the installed PHP version from YUM and need to use only XAMPP of. As I said I am not technical so if I remove php-devel installed by YUM then when I need to phpize inside the FFMPEG directory before to make && intall, then I get an error not found...! So there how I can compile FFMPEG with installed version of PHP by XAMPP? That's the point, I think will resolve everything and I truly do not have any clue to run what commands :(